# Lagrange Inversion theorem for real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis

I haven´t found a rigorous version of Lagrange's inversion theorem:

$$ x = y + f(y)$$

Where x, y are reals and $f$ is a real analytic in a interval containing $0$.

Can anybody give me a statement and the proof for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a bit more general: [The Lagrange Inversion Theorem
in the Smooth Case](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612041.pdf) by by Harold R. Parks and Steven G. Krantz.